# Show continuity of Euler gamma function using DCT

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, gamma-function

The Euler Gamma function is defined by

$$\begin{align}
&\Gamma : \{z\in \mathbb{C} : \Re(z) > 0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \\
&\Gamma(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{z-1}e^{-x}dx
\end{align}$$

My goal is to show that $\Gamma$ is continuous. I will quote the solution from my exercsce sheet below:

> Let $z_n \rightarrow z_0, \Re(z_k) > 0 \; \forall k \geq 0$. We can assume that $|z_n| \leq 1$ without loss of generality. By the Dominated Convergence Theorem:
> $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{z_n-1}e^{-x}dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{z_0-1}e^{-x}dx$$
> since $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}dx$ is integrable.

In this solution the approach seems to be that for any sequence  $z_n$ converging to $z_0$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\Gamma(z_n) = \Gamma(z_0)$, but I don't understand why it can be assumed that $|z_n|\leq1$.

Secondly, for applying DCT, $g(x) = e^{-x}$ was used. This only works if for the absolute value of the integrand: $|x^{z_n-1}e^{-x}| \leq g(x)$. But why is this true?
I tried:

$$|x^{z_n-1}e^{-x}| = e^{z_n\log{x}}x^{-1} e^{-x} = e^{\Re(z_n)\log{x}}x^{-1}e^{-x} = x^{\Re(z_n)-1}e^{-x} ~,$$
where the absolute value vanishes because $x\in(0,\infty)$.

Now why is $x^{\Re(z_n)-1} \leq 1$?

Comment: The reason we can assume $z_n\leq 1$ is because, for any sequence $\{z_n\}_n$ converging to a point $z_0$ in the unit disk, $\exists m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $z_n$ is in the unit disk $\forall n>m$. Once you have found this $m$, you can just define a new sequence $\tilde{z}_n=z_{m+n}$ and of course $|\tilde{z}_n|\leq 1$ $\forall n$.

Comment: And, the reason we can assume $|z_0|\leq 1$ in the first place is due to the recursive nature of the Gamma function, so once we have shown continuity in the unit disk we can build the function continuously using recursion everywhere else.